# How limit a number of digits in a integer?

Tags: r, digits

I have a specific column in a data frame where there are numbers with 7 digits to 10 digits. I need to standardize them to have just 7 digits. How can I do this in R?

I have

```r
dado$latitude<-c (-3005575,  -3005608,  -3005351,  -3015892843, 
    -3016114564, -3016346995, ...)
```

I need

```r
dado$latitude<-c (-3005575,  -3005608,  -3005351,  -3015892, -3016114,
    -3016346, ...)
```

Comment: Use `round`, e.g. `round(your_col, 7)`

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example

Comment: I used dado$latitude2=substr(dado$latitude,1,8) and it worked for my purpose

Comment: If you do not want to convert to character and back to integer `trunc(latitude/(10^(trunc(log10(abs(latitude))) - 6)))` will do it.

Answer (score 1):

```
dado = data.frame(
 latitude = c (-3005575,  -3005608,  -3005351,  -3015892843, -3016114564, -3016346995),
 want = c(-3005575,  -3005608,  -3005351,  -3015892, -3016114, -3016346)
)

dado$result = as.integer(with(
  dado, ifelse(latitude < 0,
    substr(latitude, start = 1, stop = 8),
    substr(latitude, start = 1, stop = 7))
))
dado
#      latitude     want   result
# 1    -3005575 -3005575 -3005575
# 2    -3005608 -3005608 -3005608
# 3    -3005351 -3005351 -3005351
# 4 -3015892843 -3015892 -3015892
# 5 -3016114564 -3016114 -3016114
# 6 -3016346995 -3016346 -3016346
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
latitude <- c(-3005575,  -3005608,  -3005351,  -3015892843, -3016114564, -3016346995)
```

One way to do this:

```r
as.integer(gsub("(-?[0-9]{7}).*", "\\1", as.character(latitude))
```

- `-?`: allow but don't require a minus sign
- `[0-9]{7}`: 7 numeric values
- `.*`: the rest of the string
- `\\1`: substitute only the matched part (between parentheses)

(You could also use `stringr::str_extract()` for this.)